# How can I tell what windows theme I'm using?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, windows-themes

I'm trying to make my application force a theme - this is straightforward as shown here: http://arbel.net/blog/archive/2006/11/03/Forcing-WPF-to-use-a-specific-Windows-theme.aspx

However, I don't know what theme I'm using now.  I'm using the Windows XP default theme, whatever that may be.  That article says

> It's important to specify the version
>   and the public key token

...where do I get that information?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to do this? What is the purpose of your program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the theme name you can call the unmanaged GetCurrentThemeName method:

```
public string GetThemeName()
{
  StringBuilder themeNameBuffer = new StringBuilder(260);
  var error = GetCurrentThemeName(themeNameBuffer, themeNameBuffer.Capacity, null, 0, null, 0);
  if(error!=0) Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(error);
  return themeNameBuffer.ToString();
}

[DllImport("uxtheme.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int GetCurrentThemeName(StringBuilder pszThemeFileName, int dwMaxNameChars, StringBuilder pszColorBuff, int dwMaxColorChars, StringBuilder pszSizeBuff, int cchMaxSizeChars);
```

You can find the version and public key token by right-clicking the theme .dll (such as PresentationFramework.Aero) in the GAC (open c:\Windows\Assembly in Exporer), or you can use code to do it.  Just loop through all loaded assemblies using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.LoadedAssemblies and find the one you want:

```
foreach(Assembly a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.LoadedAssemblies)
  if(a.Name.StartsWith("PresentationFramework."))
    return a.FullName;
```

Note that looping through the loaded assemblies will also tell you the current theme name *if* only one theme has been loaded in the current AppDomain.